# Wordpress ACF google map not working

Tags: wordpress

I tried to add google map field in ACF, but when I try to edit or add new article it show the map for sec and then diable it and wrtie:

> Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps
>   correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

What can be the problem? How can I fix it...?

Answer (score 0):

as said here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

It may be necessary to register a Google API key in order to allow the Google API to load correctly. Please follow this link to get a Google API key.

To register your Google API key, please use the ‘acf/fields/google_map/api’ filter like so in your function.php :

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
  $api['key'] = 'xxx';
  return $api;
} 
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your script..replace with your key..

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.googlemap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question. (Especially since your formatting hides the actual code - I've already edited the other one)